# Adaptando código iOS 7 para iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, atualização

Atualmente eu estou com a biblioteca do iOS 7 e pretendo atualizar a minha biblioteca para o iOS 8. Gostaria de saber qual vai ser o impacto desta atualização nos projetos que eu já possuo.

Eu conseguirei estar prestando suporte nos meus projetos do iOS 7 sem nenhum problema?

Motivo da minha pergunta, é que quando fui atualizar do iOS 6 para o iOS 7, houve um impacto enorme. Tive de refazer grande parte das telas dos meus projetos. Acabou gerando bastante retrabalho e prejuízo.

Answer (score 1):

É difícil dizer se você terá problemas ou não, isso vai variar dos componentes e dependências de cada projeto.

Você pode conferir a lista de alterações direto na documentação da Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html

A mudança não foi tão drástica quanto do `iOS 6` para o `iOS 7`. Algumas que posso pontuar para você são:

- Componente `UIAlertController` que veio para substituir o `UIAlertView` e `UIActionSheet`.
- `WKWebView` que substitui a `UIWebView`.
- Layout do teclado está mais alto devido a predição de palavras.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiseres submeter uma aplicação na store és obrigado a suportar o SDK8 da Apple e consecutivamente o novo iOS8. Há partida não deves ter tantos problemas, mas existe certas funcionalidades que foram alteradas o que ainda te vai obrigar algum trabalho.

Comment: Ainda não é obrigado suportar iOS 8. 3 dias atrás eu publiquei um aplicativo apenas suportando iOS 7.

Comment: és obrigado a suportar o SDK8. O target mínimo da aplicação, neste caso 7 é indiferente. Do site da Apple  "New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store should support iOS 8 and be optimized for iOS devices with Retina display." https://developer.apple.com/ios8/

Comment: Então, neste caso como explicaria o minha postagem com o Xcode 5 e application loader 2.9 ainda? Neste caso, como atualizei para o Xcode 6 eu sou obrigado a fazer o upload com o iOS 8. Porém, antes quando postei com o Xcode 5 não houve qualquer problema.

Comment: Nesse caso não tenho resposta para ti, só estou a tentar te dar uma explicação com base da documentação oficial da Apple e da minha experiência numa aplicação recente. Também não queria fazer um update na aplicação, por esta estar numa fase critica e com pouco tempo de desenvolvimento, mas devido as restrições da Apple tive que atualiza-la. Sinceramente, penso que por teres feito a submissão numa fase inicial que tenha sido aceite, mas não acredito que tenhas muito sucesso no futuro, mas mais uma vez, apenas minha opinião tendo em base a documentação da Apple

Comment: Opinião totalmente aceita, só estou compartilhando da experiência que tive. E agora sim, eu tive de atualizar o Xcode, e com isso sim, tive de fazer a reformulação do que foi necessário. E sim, sempre temos de adaptarmos as condições. Obrigado pela ajuda.